# passing parameter to webdriver instead of driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

I am trying to import data from excel sheet and pass that as parameter to python script, where i am also trying to take the "Browser" also as parameter from the excel file. Below are the details.

The browser is specified in "B2" cell of the excel sheet:

[image]

WorkBook name: Data.xlsx

Sheet Name: Configuration

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import alert_is_present
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
config=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Configuration')
'''b1=config["B2"].value'''
url=config["B3"].value
uid=config['B4'].value
pwd=config['B5'].value
Browser=webdriver.config['B2'].value()
'''in the above deceleration I am trying to pass the value from excel sheet, instead of writing the value directly. So from next time on wards, I can update in excel sheet with the required browser''' 

class Actions():
    def OpenApplication():
        Browser.get(url)
```

Comment: it could be that your excel B2 value does not have a closer "()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because creating the webdriver needs a closer, but you're trying to put a string on the end of `webdriver` without a closer (closer are the parentheses "()" at the end). 
try using this `if` statement.

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx') 
config=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Configuration') 
b1=config["B2"].value

if b1 == 'Chrome':
    Browser = webdriver.Chrome()
elif b1 == 'Firefox':
    Browser = webdriver.Firefox()
elif b1 == 'IE':
    Browser = webdriver.Ie()
```

Comment: trying the above statement directly caused error, so I have used below and is working. Thanks for the tip...

    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
    config=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Configuration')
    b1=config["B2"].value

    if b1=='Chrome':
        Browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif b1=='Firefox':
        Browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    elif b1=='IE':
        Browser = webdriver.Ie()

Comment: thats good news! I'll update my answer to reflect your comments

Comment: I see my mistake, I did `value()` instead of `value`.  I think the answer is good now